# Using yq to replace name of docker image

Tags: kubernetes, github-actions, yq

I'm using github actions for creating new images and pushing them to a registry.

```
    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker build . --file Dockerfile  --tag ${{secrets.DOCKER_USER}}/book:$GITHUB_SHA
```

This works perfectly. Now, I need to replace the value of the image. So I thought of using yq

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: xxxxx/book:main
```

```
    - name: Replace Image
      run: yq -i e '.spec.template.spec.containers.image |= ${{secrets.DOCKER_USER}}/guestbook:$GITHUB_SHA' argo/deployment.yaml
```

But getting this error `Error: 1:43: invalid input text "xxxx/book:..." Error: Process completed with exit code 1.`

How I would need to do this replacement?

Answer (score 2):

Use the correct json path expression to the `image` property and quote the replacement value.

Example:

```
$ yq '.spec.template.spec.containers.[0].image = "STRING"' argo/deployment.yaml 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: STRING
$ yq --version
yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version v4.34.1
```